# Using the flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use the flexbox. And I want to place the blue box to the right edge, but when it will be on the second line (when the browser's window compresses) it must to be in centre. Can you help me?

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .left-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main .left-items .item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main .right-item-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main .right-item-wrapper .right-item {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left-items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-item-wrapper">
    <div class="right-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6bqh455t/10/)

Comment: use media query

Comment: I can not use media query, because the number of red boxes can increase dynamically. Because of this, the blue box will be on another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to use `margin` to align the items...

Just use `margin-right:auto` to the `.left-items` to push the right item to the right edge and `justify-content:center` in the `.main` to align items center

**[Fiddle Link ▸](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/6bqh455t/32/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .left-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.main .left-items .item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main .right-item-wrapper .right-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left-items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-item-wrapper">
    <div class="right-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do without media query? The number of red boxes can increase dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a big `flex-grow` to the first container that will push the other container to the right when both are in the same line and when there is a wrap the blue will be centred:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-grow: 100;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right-item-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right-item {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left-items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-item-wrapper">
    <div class="right-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left-items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-item-wrapper">
    <div class="right-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a true way?

Comment: @FirstDeveloper you mean what by a true way ? :) ... it's not working like you want ? if yes than it's a true way ;)